# How to get mic to c++ from qml webgl?

Tags: c++, qml, webrtc, gstreamer

I'm making a call software using Qt and Qml, and I need to get the microphone feed from Qml running as webgl to the C++ side, if not straight to GStreamer using server.

I already have a Qt program as the client using GStreamer to push audio stream to the server. GStreamer, of course, doesn't go to the webgl client side though. I've found, that you can get permissions to use mic/camera from Qml, but I haven't found any example actually grabbing the stream from there. I've also checked out the usage of WebRTC. It seems like it could work with Qml and I have found some examples using it with GStreamer, but I haven't been able to get the combination of WebRTC and GStreamer working even with the examples.

So the full question:
How can I get the audio from the Qml running as webgl? Is there a way within Qt or do I have to go through WebRTC? If so, is there some simpler or more beginner friendly example than the [Nirbheek's gstwebrtc demos](https://github.com/centricular/gstwebrtc-demos) for connecting WebRTC to GStreamer?

Answer (score -2):

> Not the answer I wanted, but this ended up working in my case:
>
> As the C++ side is also running another Qt GUI, Qml to be specific, I
>   can use WebEngineView with html and javascript to never bother the C++
>   implementation with GStreamer for WebRTC. So currently I'm running
>   [PeerJS](https://peerjs.com/) on both sides of the connection with [PeerJS' signaling
>   server](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server) in between.
>
> I'd have preferred to use C++ with GStreamer to connect to WebRTC, but
>   I can't find other easy way for me to connect browser's audio to Qt.

edit: I apologise, this answer doesn't work in the end. I have been testing the programs on a single computer, thus I didn't realize WebGL hosted Qml doesn't run WebEngineView's Javascript on the frontend, but backend instead.